# Can I use wireless 802.1x authentication on windows for client machines that are not in the domain?

Tags: windows, wifi, 802.1

First off, I am not a sysadmin, so feel free to correct any mistakes in my question.

We have a Windows Server 2008 R2 domain with 802.1X authenticated wireless access for laptops with Windows 7 installed. Most of the laptops are in the domain, but some are not. The people using those machines do have a domain user account to access network resources, but are not logged on to the machine with that account.

How can we allow the windows 7 machines that are not in the domain to connect to the wireless network?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under advanced network properties of that SSID untick "use logged on user's credentials to connect to this network" and then you will get a prompt for the username and password or a balloon tip to say additional information required. Click on it and type domain\username and then the password. Thats it!

Comment: actually, on windows 7 it's a bit more complex: in advanced settings, choose 'user authentication'. Click on 'Settings' for PEAP, click on 'configure' for EAP-MSCHAPv2 and uncheck 'automatically use my windows logon name and password (and domain if any)'. But still, this was the right approach, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The Windows wireless client would not let you use arbitrary credentials for [PEAP-MSCHAPv2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc779326%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). But you could set up a new WLAN to use PEAP-TLS with certificates instead of password-based MSCHAPv2 authentification. Certificates can be used on non-domain machines as well with only minor limitations. See the [technet docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283023%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) for details on how to set this up.

Comment: `The Windows wireless client would not let you use arbitrary credentials` - apparently this is outdated / has changed. Try rabbid's solution instead - seems easier than setting up a CA and an additional wireless network.